# Is there any better solution for continuously checking the expiry of meeting?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, polling

I'm implementing `meeting feature`. Users come and pick slots and send to invitees. Once invitees pick the slots, the meeting gets confirmed Here I need to `cancel` the meeting if the slots expires. I'm using `scheduler` for every 2 min to perform this check. I think its bad to check frequently. Is there any other solution ?. Its a Rails 4.x application with Mysql database.

Comment: Why do you think it's bad? Also, 2 mins is not that frequently. 50 times per second - now that's frequently :)

Comment: Can a user get a slot from 11:31 till 11:43?

Comment: BTW, MySQL has internal support for [time-based events](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/events-configuration.html), there is no need to involve a scheduler.

Comment: time slots will be with 10 to 15 min difference

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thanks. I thought to avoid frequent checks.

Comment: Use the scheduler in MySQL if you want. But I wouldn't bother. Checking from your rails app is fine, even if you're doing so every 2 minutes.

Comment: Got it. thanks all :-). I would prefer using scheduler within my app.